# Ionic - Implementing phonegap-nfc, I get Ionic Native: deviceready did not fire within 5000ms

Tags: ionic-framework, plugins, nfc

I followed the official guide https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/nfc
to implement an NFC reader inside my app but I don't get any log when I try to read any type of RFID on any type of ( NFC supported ) phone

```
// Read NFC Tag - Android
// Once the reader mode is enabled, any tags that are scanned are sent to the subscriber
 let flags = this.nfc.FLAG_READER_NFC_A | this.nfc.FLAG_READER_NFC_V;
 this.readerMode$ = this.nfc.readerMode(flags).subscribe(
     tag => console.log(JSON.stringify(tag)),
     err => console.log('Error reading tag', err)
 );
```

I start thinking is it because of the

> Ionic Native: deviceready did not fire within 5000ms. This can happen when plugins are in an inconsistent state. Try removing plugins from plugins/ and reinstalling them.

warning I keep seeing since I injected NFC into the component constructor.
It's probably blocking my code. Or maybe I'm totally way off base.

Any suggestion?

> I'm using MIFARE Classic 1K 13.56 MHz ISO14443A on a Nexus 7 ( 2012 )
> device. They can be readable from other apps like NFC Tools so I guess
> they're supported

Comment: What type of NFC Tag are you using (Make and Model)? As it might not be of the NfcA or NfcV type (You could try broadening the types by adding `FLAG_READER_NFC_B` and `FLAG_READER_NFC_F` to the flags)

Comment: @Andrew I'm using MIFARE Classic 1K 13.56 MHz ISO14443A on a Nexus 7 ( 2012 ) device. They can be readable from other apps like NFC Tools so I guess they're supported. I tried adding those flags but nothing changes. The device makes a sound when I get the RFID close to it but I don't get any logs or errors. Like the plugin was totally ignored. That's why I suppose is related to that warning

Comment: NFC tools app is saying that is NfcA type, NdefFormatable anyway

Comment: You had the right flags for that type of Tag, the other flags suggestion was for the possibility you were using another Tag Type, BUT note that Mifare Classic Tag are not a standard NFC Forum Tag type and might not be supported on all hardware so well (But if it showing NdefFormatable it is showing as well supported on the Nexus 7)